# How do i add another components on the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf

Struggling, I need a button to open up a window but below the MainWindow in C#. Like in a website you can open other pages but the master page layout doesn't change only the page you are viewing shows differently.

I need similar thing. I have components (tools i added from toolbox) on my MainWindow.xaml so for example if i click on a button i named new student, a tabbed-window where i can capture student details must appear but it must not be a separate windows it must appear within the mainwindow and seem like a one thing. Forgive for my English. I hope someone will understand me though, thanks in advance. I want to have components/functionality according a specific button click but constant Mainwindow, the one with "File" "Edit" "View" "Help".

Comment: possible duplicate of [MDI Applications in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651424/mdi-applications-in-wpf)

Comment: You will want to use what is called a POPUP, take a look here:  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=popup%20wpf   Remember that with WPF a Popup is wholly contained in the main window and cannot go beyond it.

Comment: You can also add a TabControl with TabItems.  When a button is clieck the tabcontrol's current item is set the proper one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different solutions to you problem, but Visual Studio doesn't quite have something like the Master View option through ASP .NET with webforms.

**Option One**
Using *TabControl*. This option is the easiest solution to your problem. The GUI in Visual studio has support for adding components to each tab, which nothing else has. This is the closest component to something like multi-panels in Java, but it will still create the Tabs, which may not be what you are looking for.

**Option Two**
Using multiple *Panel*s over one another. With this option, you can add multiple panels to your main window and layer each panel over one another. You can add a button or other control which will hide each panel and all of its contents. This is a great solution if you don't want tabs, but it can be frustrating to create in Visual Studio since you must move each panel away from another in order to add/remove/adjust the components on the underlying panel.

Of course there are still a few more controls you can use to produce the results you are looking for, but these are probably the most applicable solutions to your problem.

Comment: +1. Seems like a reasonable solution. If I understand it, RuthGoodloser
do not want a popup or another window. Using tabs / panes will handle all this IN the main window.